# Comparing 2 objects in XML, ideas needed

Tags: python, xml, perl

I am thinking about producing an intelligent report that depicts results of a comparison of `n` XML config files against a set of rules.

```
a.b.Default.StartTime=00:00:00
a.b.Default.SomePath:exists
a.b.Default.BeginString:value_a|value_b
```

I am pushing for 3 assertion types:

1. There is a key that has a particular value
2. There is a key that has any value. Key must exists and something must be assigned to it
3. There is a key that has either value A or value B

**Is there a library I can use to handle this gracefully?**

Any direction towards `Perl`, `Python` would be most appreciated

Comment: How much of this are you expecting from a library?  To parse XMLs nicely and in various ways, yes there are good ones for that, by all means. I wouldn't expect a library to have this particular functionality. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe run your `xml` through an *xml schema validation* tool. If you're using python, it's supported by the [lxml](http://lxml.de/validation.html) library. More information on xml schema can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp).

You can also use a library such as [xmltodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict) to load your xml data into a python dictionary, then run a [cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/) validation schema on it.

Comment: On the Perl side, XML::LibXML can be used for schema validation.

Answer (score 1):

Perl libraries [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0125/LibXML.pod) and [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) are easy to recommend for handling XML. They will parse XML and hand you Perl data structures which you can then work with.

Documentation for `XML::LibXML`, which provides interface to `libxml2`, is available in a number of separate pages. You may want to first look at [`XML::LIbXML::Reader`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0125/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod), a pull-parser which iterates through the document stream as opposed to loading the whole tree, and perhaps the ones on [`XPath context`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0125/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod) and [`Schema validation`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0125/lib/XML/LibXML/Schema.pod).

The `XML::Twig` can load small documents as a tree, or process "huge" ones in a combined stream/tree mode.  It has a lot of (additional) documentation at [`xmltwig.org`](http://www.xmltwig.org/xmltwig/).

Both of these modules are full-blown true XML libraries. For one thing, both make good use of [`XPath expressions`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), helping with search through the document for elemens with particular properties or values.